# Powershell - "Access to the path is denied" when attempting to redirect output to a file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to redirect console output from a TFS command to a file with the following command:

```
witadmin listfields /collection:blahblah:8080/tfs/TPC > TFSfields.txt
```

but I get an error:

```
"Access to the path 'C:\....\TFSfields.txt is denied"
```

and also further down:

```
OpenError: (:) [Out-File], UnauthorizedAccess
```

I'm fairly new to PowerShell, so I'm not sure how I could not have access to create a file in a directory on my own machine. I'm assuming I'm missing something simple. When I run the command without redirecting output, it outputs what I expect to the screen.

Comment: Did you run Powershell as Administrator?

Comment: Probably not the problem, but is there a TFSfields.txt directory at that location?

Comment: I typed "powershell" into the windows explorer navigation bar from the folder I wanted to start in, so I guess I didn't run as administrator. And no, TFSfields.txt is not a directory or an existing file

Comment: To run as admin, right-click on the powershell icon on the taskbar and choose 'Run as administrator'. Lack of admin privileges is most probably the issue

Comment: Running as Administrator fixed the issue. I really don't like that. If the user that is currently logged in has permission to create a file in a directory, then why would powershell, run by said user, not have permission to create a file in that directory?

Comment: You should not have to 'Run As Administrator' if the user running PowerShell has access to create files in the target folder. Be more specific about the path you are getting an error with, or specify a full path for your output file. Maybe try `witadmin listfields /collection:blahblah:8080/tfs/TPC > "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\TFSfields.txt"` That will create the file on the current user's desktop.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician You're right. I didn't realize Program Files (x86) is protected directory. Is that new in Windows 8? At any rate, running PowerShell as administrator solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: With the -OutFile parameter, I guess powershell expects to define the type of the file with an extension based on what is that you are trying to redirect/download.  For Eg) I tried to download a zip file using wget and ran into an issue were I was redirecting to just a folder instead of -OutFile "C:\tmp\tmp.zip" which fixed the issue. @DaveNovelli

Comment: Please write an answer to your own question and mark this as answered...
And have a look into how UAC is intended to work on Windows. It's a good thing :)